# 8-Port SATA PCIex4 non-raid?

Tags: pcie, sata

I would like to add some SATA ports to older servers (2 x PCIe x4, 1 x PCIe x 8) and I need to be able to use the max. speed of the HDDs attached to them - in parallel/all at the same time.

The HDDs are capable of delivering ~ 220MB/s read/write speed.

What I do find, are PCIe x1 cards like

```
InLine 76617G, 8x SATA 6Gb/s, PCIe 2.0 x1
```

but these obviously max out at some 750 MB/s interface speed. Probably under normal load conditions that would be fine to serve 3 HDDs at a time, however, as mentioned, I'd need at least 1.6GB/s bandwidth.

There are some older PCIex8 RAID controllers like the Areca 1220, but these unfortunately deliver only a 400MB/s bandwidth (actually trying to replace these) even when used in non-RAID mode with just "pass through" disks.

I also have been able to find a 8-port PCIe x2 card from Syba, which comes closest. Or alternately I could use two 4-port PCIe x2 cards as offered on Amazon. With the backdraw of losing 1 PCIe x 4 port.

So back to the title of this question: Is there a 8port SATA 6g PCIe x4 non-raid card - preferably below $80.

Comment: Its too bad you have all of those hdd as even a single sata ssd can do 550 read and 400+ write depending on the make/model.

Comment: @cybernard They are 10TB Seagate Ironwolfs. The NVMe in my notebook can do 3.5GB/s thank you very much. Please next time focus on the question. Kthx

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this
http://www.ascendtech.us/lsi-sas9211-8i-6gb-s-raid-card-3wdv5_i_cntcrdlsi03wdv5.aspx?agent=froogle#

It has 2 visible connect which each support 4 hard drives through a cable which I suspect isn't included in the cost.

You easily get adaptec cards that will do the speed you want, but there all like $500-$1000 so I won't even waste your time with examples.

---

**Forget controllers and all of that if all you want is speed.**

I can get you the speed you need/want, but not the price. [HERE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077YHFJZM)

[image: pcie m.2]
Here is a m.2 that meets your speed requirements
From www.newegg.com:

It breaks the budget a bit, buts its name brand.
[image]

Samsung a bit more:
[image]

[image]

Want even faster:

[image]

You can get 2 cheaper ones and do a software RAID.

Comment: The LSI controller might be worth a try, although I do not feel very confident to use a SAS controller to handle SATA HDDs.
As mentioned in my comment above, the HDDs are - relatively new - 10TB Seagate Ironwolfs. The key here is to get capacity - at their speed - not faster HDDs.

Comment: @Perlator   "I'd need at least 1.6GB/s"  To me that meant you were speed focused.  I have a SAS controller right now with SFF-8087 connectors on the card and 7 SATA hard drive plugged in.  Apdatec 71685, which I believe handle 24 hdd in this fashion with out SATA expandors 256 with expandors.  Unfortunately the card is out of your budget probably by a factor of 6.

Comment: @Perlator    https://www.ebay.com/itm/Adaptec-PMC-ASR-71685-24-Port-6Gbp-s-SAS-PCi-E-RAID-Controller/372460184298?hash=item56b85b62ea:g:i7AAAOSw38Vbt9Xj  This card is only $100 now on ebay and you can use it as a JBOD if you want.